# How to configure DBeaver to save files without a BOM for UTF files?

Tags: encoding, dbeaver

I am looking for the equivalent setting as the PGADMIN setting `Write BOM for UTF files` which will cause saved files to be saved with/without the BOM.

I've found settings in DBeaver when exporting data, but nothing that would configure new (or existing) files to be saved without the BOM.

[image]

How do I configure DBeaver to save files without a BOM for UTF files/

Comment: What are you using on these files that is too stupid to understand the BOM? Why not just cut it out after the fact if you must -- it's the first 3 bytes.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: probably `psql` ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name seems to work fine for me with `-f file` and `< file`

Comment: yes, psql. And the questions is for configuring DBeaver.  There are numerous ways to alter the file after the fact, which is what I'm doing now.

Comment: Can you also configure to import CSV files with/without BOM?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file

Answer (score 0):

## Using `sed`

You can always cut out three bytes (the bom) with `sed`

```
sed -i '1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' *.txt
```

That'll actually do it in place.